# How to debug "Your User ID is invalid. Kindly use a valid API Key and User ID combination" in Android?

Tags: android, post, request

I am new to Android, I am getting this in my logcat:

> "status":false,"msg":"Your User ID is invalid. Kindly use a valid API Key and User ID combination"

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String url = "https://json.astrologyapi.com/v1/monthly_panchang";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }

    ){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            params.put("username","602845");
            params.put("password","dea8c55922286904e4c34757ed1fcf09");
            return params;
        }
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Authorization", "Token <token>");
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(postRequest);

}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you proof-read your question? Please correct the errors (hint: parts of the code are in the normal text).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your API auth token here:

```
params.put("Authorization", "Token <token>");
```

Comment: headers.put("Authorization", "dea8c55922286904e4c34757ed1fcf09");
now my logcat saying this com.android.volley.AuthFailureError

Comment: Ok don't share your auth token here..its sensitive information.. Are you sure you username and password or correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Username", "602826");
            headers.put("Password", "cb");
            String credentials = "602826" + ":" + "cb";
            String auth = "Basic "
                    + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(),
                    Base64.NO_WRAP);
            headers.put("Authorization", auth);
            // headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;

        }
```

i have solved my problem.